# MobileFirst 7.0 Hybrid App - Android version has issue on scrolling when new Android System Webview is enabled

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

We have this issue in our Android version starting December 2016 when Android System Webview and Chrome been updated. We had installed the latest iFix for MFP 7.0 but no effect. Is there a investigation at IBM end to fix this issue? The solution we found is to uninstall the Android System Webview, but we cannot ask each of our users to uninstall this specific Android app. Anyone who has encountered this and has a better solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is out of the MobileFirst Platform control, as it cannot control the status / version of the WebView provided by the Android system.

I know that recently Google released updated Chrome WebView (versions 53 and 54) which contain several bugs.

As you've mentioned, you can uninstall this (or update it, from the Google Play Store), and this is an action that has to be done by the end-user.

The only known workaround is for the end user to update the WebView from the Play Store (if it is not auto-updated).

To iterate, from the MobileFirst Platform framework perspective, the application consumes the WebView that is provided by the OS and therefore has no control over the behaviour of the WebView.

Perhaps you can request users to update the WebView by sending a notification from the MobileFirst Console, a push notification and alike.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Current chrome version is 55. There are coupple of discussions online and I think Google is working on the next release as this is an identified issue. We will wait for the new version then and test it again.